# Right way to apply pre-trained scikit-learn model to dask array?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask

I have a scikit-learn model, which has  already been trained. It takes 8 features as an input.
Now I would like to apply that model to an arbitrary big dask array (of shape `(n_samples, 8)`)  and write the result to disk.
I fail at applying my model to a dask array and getting back a dask array.

Setup:

```
import dask.array as da
from dask import delayed

# pre-trained classifier/model already exists
# I will refer to this model as "clf"

# test data
X = da.full((100,8), 0)

# this works fine, but returns a numpy array...
y_predicted = clf.predict(X)
```

What I have tried

```
# 1. intention: apply classifier to each row (features)
y_predicted = da.apply_along_axis(clf.pedict, 1, X)
# fails with
# AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'pedict'

# 2. apply blocks
y_predicted = da.map_blocks(clf.predict, X)
# quickly runs out of memory, process killed 

# 3. write a delayed function that returns a dask array
@delayed
def predict_delayed(da_array):
    return da.from_array(clf.predict(da_array))
    
y_predicted = predict_delayed(X)
y_predicted.compute()
#  fails with TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'method'>
```

I have spent quite some time on this and I am quite clueless on how to proceed.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! when asking questions, it's really helpful if you can provide a [mre] which is complete and lets us run your code. you almost have one here, but it's not quite complete! could you give us a full example that generates clf, e.g. from random data?

Comment: > object has no attribute 'pedict' (there is a typo here)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, here is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import dask.array as da
from dask import delayed

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RF

n_samples = 1000
# random training data
X_train = da.random.random((n_samples,8))
y_train = da.random.randint(0, 2, n_samples)

rf = RF(random_state = 42, n_estimators=50)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# some data to predict on
X_new = da.random.random((n_samples,8))

# 1. option: delayed function
@delayed
def predict_delayed(da_array: da.array) -> da.array:
    return da.from_array(rf.predict(da_array))

y_predicted = predict_delayed(X_new)

# 2. option: map_blocks
# (key was here to supply drop_axis and dtype arguments)
y_predicted = da.map_blocks(rf.predict, X_new, dtype="i8", drop_axis=1)
```